# "Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server (HTTP 404)" when hosted on Azure

Tags: azure, iis, mediawiki, visual-editor, parsoid

I set up 2 mediawikis. One is running on an inhouse server with IIS and the public one is hosted on Azure. They both have the same settings in localsettings.php.

But on IIS the visual editor works and on Azure I get this error **"Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server (HTTP 404)"**

Since the localsettings is the same it can't be a problem with userrights. It may have something to do with the SSL certificate on Azure. But I couldn't find a solution yet.

Anyhone have suggestions?

Comment: Does [this link](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T269673) useful to you ?

Comment: No, I'm don't have accented characters in title. And anyway I can't open the visual editor even for existing pages, not just when creating new ones.

Comment: I've got the same Error after fiddling with my firewall. Didn't find a solution yet, but could be a problem with the firewall settings.